# using CSS psuedo-class :first-child

Tags: html, css, menu, css-selectors

Trying to set up a menu so that I have border-left on each menu item but the border is excluded from the first item.

site: http://www.rogersinternational.com

CSS:

```
#access {
 background: #414731;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 900px;
 height: 42px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#access .menu-header,
div.menu {
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-left: 14px;
 width: 900px;
}
#access .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#access a {
 color: #a5af86;
 line-height: 38px;
 padding: 0 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-left: 1px solid #5e6549;
}
#access a:first-child { border: none }
#access ul ul {
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 38px;
 left: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 180px;
 z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul li { min-width: 180px }
#access ul ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
 background: #414731;
 line-height: 1em;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 160px;
 height: auto;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
 background: #414731;
 color: #fff;
}
```

Menu:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/about">Company Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/solutions">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/photo-gallery">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/technical-specs">Technical Specs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rogersinternational.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can get it to recognize the psuedo-class in firebug, but the effect doesn't take place.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your `:first-child` style?

Comment: not worried about x-browser compatibility?

Comment: @BoltClock `#access a:first-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also put an id on your first li:

```
<li id="first">
```

and edit your style like so:

```
#access #first a { border: none }
```

i made those changes here:
http://jsbin.com/oyafe3

Comment: Thanks @rquinn, good idea, not sure why that wasn't my first approach.

Comment: Because then it wouldn't be all CSS3 wonderful, of course. :D

Comment: @Jared Farrish: `:first-child` isn't new in CSS3. Pretty much the only browser not supporting it is IE<=6.

Comment: Also, if you want it to be cross-browser, class it. <a class="noborder" ... a.noborder { border: none }

Comment: @Jared Farrish sometimes I tend to go with the fancy and forget the practical ;)

Comment: All Browser above IE6 supports the :first-child selector. So you can reduce your markup... BTW it is the more elegant way to use pseudo selectors

Comment: @blackessej - That's the spirit! 8^)

Comment: @gearsdigital - Almost (and I agree with your last statement). But, IE8 has a slight problem: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @gearsdigital - i agree, if you don't need to worry about ie6, your solution is more elegant, especially if you use the id selector rather than the !important.

Comment: @rquinn Full Ack :) But there are many ways to solve problems... :) @Jared Farrish I know that but i've no practical issus with that. Not only because i know the problem. Btw Thanks for your mention!

Answer (score 4):

```
.menu li:first-child a{
    border: none!important;
}
```

Same result you will get with that:

```
#access .menu li:first-child a{
    border: none;
}
```

For explanation:

Your Border was defined here:

```
#access a {
    border-left: 1px solid #5E6549;
    …
}
```

`.menu li:first-child` won't match because the border is not defined here.

`.menu li:first-child a` won't work because `#access a` has an higher specifty.

So you have to increase the specifty by adding the **!important** rule

Comment: I don't think in this case it is.

Comment: It is necessary. See my update above. Without important: http://jsfiddle.net/3hBeE/ and with important: http://jsfiddle.net/3hBeE/1/

Comment: Re edit: the `:first-child` pseudo-class *already* increases the specificity. You just need to qualify it with the `#access` ID instead of the `.menu` class to match with `#access a`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the border to all the elements. Then remove it from the first-child.

```
.menu li { border-left:1px solid black; }
.menu li:first-child { border-left:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu li:first-child a {
  border: none!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```